# Enabling Brotli compression on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, compression, gzip, iis-8.5, web.config

My team us currently trying to install Brotli compression on a VPS: Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS8.5 using the 64bit module that can be downloaded here: https://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed/products/iisbrotli

But whatever we try, when I fill out the https domain name under: https://tools.keycdn.com/brotli-test
I get a message

> Negative! www.zorgbeurs.nl does not support Brotli compression.

In IIS these two modules are active for that site:
DynamicCompressionModule
StaticCompressionModule

What we've tried so far:

Added this to the applicationHost.Config file:

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="br" dll="C:\inetpub\iisbrotli64.dll" />
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
          <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>                             
    </httpCompression>
```

I tried with out without the gzip line `<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />`

I've stopped and started IIS.

I wanted to check if caching was the issue so I cleared files in folders:
"C:\Windows\Temp", "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root" and "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" and then restarted the webserver.

In the web.config of the site I tried with and without this line in the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Still I see this in Chrome dev console for the 200 request to zorgbeurs.nl:

Response Headers

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
>   Cache-Control:private
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>   Content-Length:14252
>   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Date:Fri, 30 Dec 2016 19:01:48 GMT
>   Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   Set-Cookie:showcookiebar=false; path=/
>   Vary:Accept-Encoding
>   X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

It's as if the configuration is completely ignored.

What else can I try?

Comment: Does your request header include br in accept-encoding header?

Comment: Thanks. Response Header contains: `Content-Encoding:gzip`, Request Headers contains `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br`...what else can I do?

Comment: You should remove gzip config otherwise iis prioritize gzip over br. Did u check it?if yes whst's the response content-encoding?

Answer (score 6):

It appears the Brotli module you referenced requires a paid license, so I haven't tried it, but I encountered a similar issue with my own [open source Brotli plugin for IIS](https://github.com/saucecontrol/BrotliIIS).

Current browsers advertise Brotli support after `gzip` and `deflate` in the `Accept-Encoding` header.  Typical headers will look like: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`.

The [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4) gives no specific guidance on how to choose from many `Accept-Encoding` values with the same priority, so it would be acceptable to return `br` content to those clients.  However, IIS will choose the first one (left to right) that matches one of its configured compression schemes. This means it won't choose `br` if either `gzip` or `deflate` compression is also enabled.

The obvious solution is to disable `gzip` and `deflate` on your server so that `br` is the only match.  However, because roughly 20-25% of Internet users (as of early 2018) are still using older web browsers that don't support Brotli, you probably want to keep `gzip` enabled on your server to support compression for those clients, at least for a while longer.

If you wish to leave both (or all three) schemes enabled, you must, therefore, take some action to force IIS to choose `br` when acceptable.  To accomplish this, you can modify the `Accept-Encoding` header value on requests as they enter your IIS pipeline.  The [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) makes it easy.

The `Accept-Encoding` header is represented by the `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` Server Variable in the IIS pipeline, and you can modify it before it reaches the Compression Module(s).  Here is a sample configuration:

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Prioritize Brotli">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="\bbr(?!;q=0)\b" />
            </conditions>
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="br" />
            </serverVariables>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rule above simply looks for the string `br` (surrounded by word boundaries and not immediately followed by `;q=0`) in the `Accept-Encoding` header and re-writes it to be just plain `br`, giving IIS only one choice.

Note that the default URL Rewrite configuration does not allow modification of the `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` variable.  The `allowedServerVariables` element overrides that restriction and must be configured in `applicationHost.config`.  The rewrite rule can then be defined at any level in the config hierarchy, although it probably makes sense to make it global.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that Microsoft released their own new [compression plugin for Brotli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview).

Answer (score 2):

Brotli compression is now officially supported on IIS:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview

https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Compression

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.iisbrotli.com/documentation) all versions of IIS from 8.5 up no longer allow preference of compression schemes to be configured at the server level. Since browsers must "ask" the server which compression schemes it supports, and all browsers have Brotli behind gzip, no one will be able to use Brotli on IIS 8.5 onwards.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/saucecontrol/BrotliIIS might help you with the problem